# Select box disappears on overlapping of date picker

Tags: java, jsp, select

I am using  a select box :

When I click on date picker, the calender popup opens. The select box disappears on overlap of calender popup with the select box.  It is working fine with Chrome & Mozilla. It is not working on IE 8.

Any solution to overcome this problem?

Thank you,
SK

Comment: Screenshot, code snippet? Just asking.

Answer (score 1):

IE 8 has some problem . use jquery date picker in works in IE8 http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/